# How to post a task in selected column of imported jsonData node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, backend

i am a beginner in javascript and therefore would need some help with this task.

I have a columns.json file that is filled with tasks,  which I have already Imported with

`const jsonData = require('./data/columns.json');`

now I have to implement a post request which posts a new task to a column in the Json file. The Number in the request Bdoy specifies the column to which the task should be added. The response is the newly calculated id of that task.
the request body looks like this:

```
{
"column": Number,
"title": String,
"text": String, 
"taskTags: Array[String]
}
```

The Statuscode is 201.

Response - Body:

```
{ 
"id": String
}
```

I have successfully implemented the function which calculates the new ID of the Task.
For the POST request I have tried this:

```
app.post('/api/tasks', (req, res) => {
            body = '';
            
            req.on('data', chunk => {
                body += chunk.toString();
            });
            
            req.on('end', () => {
                if(body.length > 0) {
                    
                    console.log(body);
                    let newData = qs.parse(body);
                    console.log(newData);
                    
                    
                    if( !newData.title || !newData.text || isNaN(newData.column)) {
                        res.writeHead(400);
                        res.end();
                    } else {
                        let newId = calculateInitialTaskIdCounter();
                       let newTask = {
                            id: newId,
                            column: newData.column,
                            title: newData.title,
                            text: newData.text,
                            taskTags: newData.taskTags || []
                        };
                        const target = jsonData.find(column => column.id == newData.column);
                        if (target) {
                          target.tasks.push(newTask);
                        
                        res.writeHead(201, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                        res.end(JSON.stringify({id: newId}));
                      } else  {       
                
                    res.writeHead(400);
                    res.end();
                  }
                }
            }else {
              res.writeHead(400);
      res.end();
     }
 });
            
});
```

but it sais Cannot GET /api/tasks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting wrong route. You have defined a POST route `POST /api/tasks` thats why you are getting the error `Cannot GET /api/tasks`

If you are trying with postman or something similar change the request type to POST in the application. Or if you are invoking the api using and http client then you have to change the api calling method from `get` to `post`